# Unable to write memory with memcpy, but fine with WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c++, winapi, memcpy

I am writing an application to load a DLL of myself, and rewrite some code in the target process to achieve something. I have checked the memory block with Cheat Engine, and found that the memory region I want to rewrite is "Execute / Read only". But it is strange that (At least for me) I am able to rewrite the memory block using WriteProcessMemory by an external program, but not using memcpy by the DLL of myself that I loaded into the memory of the target process.

Is there any other way to rewrite the opcode within the process, or do I need to use WriteProcessMemory to rewrite it?

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory` likely bypasses the memory page access protection. `memcpy` is just a plain for-loop under the hood. Can you not call `WriteProcessMemory` on the same process you are in?

Comment: My spidey senses are tingling here... even if you had a legitimate reason to do that (and you **don't**, regardless of why you think you do or what you rationale is) if you can't figure out why `memcpy` fails, then you aren't qualified to do what you're trying to do. Sorry for being blunt.

Comment: @Colonel Er, no. That's now it. WriteProcessMemory modifies the protection. Do that and you are good to go with memcpy. for loops are not relevant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's what I meant. `memcpy` is a userland function, so it will trigger a segfault just like a regular byte-copying for loop, whereas `WriteProcessMemory` presumably bypasses page protection.

Answer (score 1):

To change executable memory you generally need to use [`VirtualProtect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the access flags for the memory pages you want to write to. `WriteProcessMemory()` presumably sets these flags for you.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not: "*lpBaseAddress [in] A pointer to the base address in the specified process to which data is written. **Before data transfer occurs, the system verifies that all data in the base address and memory of the specified size is accessible for write access, and if it is not accessible, the function fails**.*".  I doubt (but I could be wrong) that the "verify for write access" includes changing the access flags of the memory being written to.  But, since `WriteProcessMemory()` is primarily meant for debuggers, maybe it does.

Comment: @Remy WPM does modify the protection